# Laravel mail function - change the recipients

Tags: php, email, laravel

I am not exactly sure if this is SO scope, but I can't find the solution in the docs.

I got my hands on a complete Laravel project.[image: root structure]

The structure of the root is seen on the right of the Total Commander window.

Next is the public_html folder [image: public_html]

The problem is the email sending portion. On all views the form has the method **POST** and the action **/mail/** which is suppose to send the email. It does sent, however I do not know where do I change the recipient, because I want all the contact emails to come to a different address.

I have tried searching in the app folder but the controllers seem to be completely empty or have basic methods to display a view.

I have tried changing the email in the .contactemail file.

I have tried to change the email in the postmaster.php file.

I have tried to set the default "to" array in the app/config/mail.php, as I read in the docs that it would override it for all email sending (it said it is useful for dev purposes).

None of those methods yielded the result I needed.

I know this service sends the emails, because the old recipient gets the emails still.

Do any of you Laravel developers have any idea where else I can look to change it or find where the /mail/ function is located? I think I went through all the folders and still no luck.

Comment: When you post the form, it will go to a specific route, which will point to a function in a controller. In this case, what route does this form point to (show us the route) and then which function inside which controller handles this (show us the controller).

Comment: Where can I check the route? The app/controllers only has two controllers - BaseController which has only a setupLayout function and a HomeController which has a showWelcome which also loads a view. Or am I not understanding the question correctly?

Comment: If possible, can we have a chat in the chatroom? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96842/laravel

Comment: See your routes in `App/http/routes.php` update the question with what you see there

Comment: There is no http folder in the app folder.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like you have Laravel 4, because of the following structure:

```
ftp://0125534@37.140.192.138/
    app/
    bootstrap/
    vendor/
    workbench/
    composer
    .htaccess
```

The public folder looks like is:

```
public_html/public/
```

Said that, your `routes.php` file should be located at `app/` folder. Inside of it, try to find the respective url. Also, people get do some practices that you may consider to take a look:

1. Config files (app/config): developers declared things there like emails, names, addresses and others.
2. Services (app/helpers or app/services): developers declared some classes that have in charge a bag of common functions. Take a look there if is there a mysterious class handling email functions.

Comment: I posted the full code of the route.php in the chatroom.  chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96842/laravel You may see it, if you like

Comment: To Edit: i posted the structure in the original post. None of these folder exist =(